# IOS notification bulk internal server error 500

Tags: php, ios, notifications, push

Currently we’re trying to send push notificatons to our iOS developers with their UDID’s. When testing the following script I recieved the notification properly but when sending a bulk (lets say 2000) we’re getting a Internal Server Error (500) message.

I’ve read a couple of things like sending to many notifications true the pipe which results in a closed connection from Apple.

Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong?

```
include ('functions/functions.php');

function sendNotification($deviceID, $message)
{   
    // Provide the Host Information.
    $tHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $tPort = 2195;

    // Provide the Certificate and Key Data.
    $tCert = 'pk.pem';

    // Provide the Private Key Passphrase (alternatively you can keep this secrete
    // and enter the key manually on the terminal -> remove relevant line from code).
    // Replace XXXXX with your Passphrase
    $tPassphrase = 'xxx';

    // Provide the Device Identifier (Ensure that the Identifier does not have spaces in it).
    // Replace this token with the token of the iOS device that is to receive the notification.
    //$tToken = $value;

    // The message that is to appear on the dialog.
    $tAlert = $message;

    // The Badge Number for the Application Icon (integer >=0).
    $tBadge = 1;

    // Audible Notification Option.
    $tSound = 'default';

    // The content that is returned by the LiveCode "pushNotificationReceived" message.
    $tPayload = $message;

    // Create the message content that is to be sent to the device.
    $tBody['aps'] = array (
        'alert' => $tAlert,
        'badge' => $tBadge,
        'sound' => $tSound,
        );
    $tBody ['payload'] = $tPayload;

    // Encode the body to JSON.
    $tBody = json_encode ($tBody);

    // Create the Socket Stream.
    $tContext = stream_context_create ();
    stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);

    // Remove this line if you would like to enter the Private Key Passphrase manually.
    stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassphrase);

    // Open the Connection to the APNS Server.
    $tSocket = stream_socket_client ('ssl://'.$tHost.':'.$tPort, $error, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $tContext);

    // Check if we were able to open a socket.
    if (!$tSocket)
        exit ("APNS Connection Failed: $error $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    // Build the Binary Notification.
    $tMsg = chr (0) . chr (0) . chr (32) . pack ('H*', $deviceID) . pack ('n', strlen ($tBody)) . $tBody;

    // Send the Notification to the Server.
    $tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));    

    /*if ($tResult)
        echo 'Delivered Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Could not Deliver Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;*/

    // Close the Connection to the Server.
    fclose ($tSocket);
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are opening/closing the SSL connection with server for each notification - this is not a good idea. Try sending all the notifications within a single connection - simply put a 10ms or so of sleep between each transmission.

Comment: @rokjarc Thanks for the answer, can you tell how to add the sleep in the code and how to make the single connection?

Comment: @user3355847 Are you really testing with 2000 difference devices? If not, Apple may block you because you're attempting to contact the same device too often. To make a PHP script wait for 500 milliseconds, use usleep(500000).

Comment: @Mark We test with many different devices. Can you show me how to implement usleep in my code and should that stop the error?

Comment: @Babidi what is "many"? You use put `usleep();` somewhere in the repeat loop that calls sendNotification function 2000 times.

Comment: Actually Apple's server doesn't reject you if you try to send 2000 messages to same device - but not all messages will go trough. However Apple's server does reject you if you make 2000 connections in a few seconds. That is why you should open a connection a send all the messages during one connection - with a pause between each of them. You can take a look at the source of [ApnsPHP](https://github.com/duccio/ApnsPHP) for an example on how it can be done. Check function send() in ApnsPHP/Push.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have an array $devices with device ID's. You can use a repeat loop and include the sleep function:

```
$message = 'Nice to meet you.';
foreach ($devices as $deviceID) {
  sendNotification($deviceID, $message);
  usleep(500000);
}
```

However, if you're not actually testing with 2000 *different* devices, Apple may still block your requests.